# Visual Studio Code dotnet: command not found (Linux mint)

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, .net-core, linux-mint

In the terminal in Visual studio code I try to call e.g. dotnet --version I get this (Linuxmint / ubuntu):

```
sh-4.4$ dotnet --version
sh: dotnet: command not found
```

When I try from a terminal with the follow commands it works:

```
jesper@jesper-spand:~$ which dotnet
/usr/local/bin/dotnet
jesper@jesper-spand:~$ dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.403
 Commit:    04e15494b6

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     linuxmint
 OS Version:  19
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         linuxmint.19-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.403/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.5
  Commit:  290303f510

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.403 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.5 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.5 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.5 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
jesper@jesper-spand:~$ echo %PATH%
%PATH%
jesper@jesper-spand:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/jesper/.dotnet/tools
jesper@jesper-spand:~
```

Any idea how the terminal in Visual Studio Code can use dotnet?

/Jesper

Comment: Configure VSCode to use Bash instead of Bourne shell.

Comment: I press F1 and select "Shell launcher: Launch"  Select:  bash   /bin/bash

But still get:
jesper@jesper-spand:~/web/MvcMovie$ dotnet --version
bash: dotnet: command not found